# In Java is it correct to allow subclass to alter superclass private fields via public setter method?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Please look at the code below

```
Class Employee{

    private String name;
    private String id;

    public String getName(){ return name; }

    public void setName(String name){ this.name = name; }

    public String getId(){ return id; }

    public void setId(String id){ this.id = id; }

}

Class Teacher extends Employee{

    private double salary;
}
```

Now my question is If I am creating an object of Teacher , then it does not make sense without the Teacher object having a name and id. I can set the same for teacher object via public setters of Employee but it it correct ?

```
Teacher t1 = new Teacher();
t1.setName("aaa");
t1.setId("224");
t1.salary = 200.00;

System.out.println(t1.toString());
```

I am asking this question as my understanding is if the field is private it should be used only via getters . But in the example provided above Teacher object will not make sense without having a Name or Id .

If it is correct then why not make the field public in the first place? What is the advantage in using it private and then allowing access via public setter ?

If it is not correct please provide an example of how the above Employee and Teacher class should be implemented ?

Comment: "in the example provided above Teacher object will not make sense without having a Name or Id" -> which is why those two fields should be part of the `Employee` constructor. The idea is that after the constructor completes your object is in a valid, useable state. If your object *isn't* in a valid, useable state (because important fields aren't set) then your constructor is wrong.

Comment: On another note, do only `Teacher`s get paid? Salary makes much more sense in `Employee`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question seem to show a confusion between two concepts rather independant:

- encapsulation
- creation of objects

Encapsulation: it is better design to define private variables. Then you can not corrupt the object from outside. You must use setter to modify your employee.

But, if you trust Teacher, it could modify Employee as a subclass, without setter, it is faster to code (but little risky: if you have to change the setter in employee, Teacher wont get it, ...).

Creation of objects: you should pass certain values to the variables, or they are defined by default (or auto-built ...)

=> you can decide that Teacher have well defined values (default), or that you must give these values (mandatory). It is your design.

After that, you can change them directly or by setters of Employee (=> first concept of encapsulation).

Answer (score 1):

> then it does not make sense without the Teacher object having a name and id. I can set the same for teacher object via public setters of Employee but it it correct ?

This is where exactly constructor comes into picture. You need to pass them before you are using it.

Thumbrule : When you want something while building it, you need to force them to pass on constructor.